# chaing a variable in a public method by a private method java

Tags: java, variables, private, public

Is it possible to modify a variable called in a public method by a private method within the public method?

example:   // node.left node.right called in constructor so never mind

```
public boolean isFull(){
  Node node = root;
  int left;
  int right;
  left = isFullLeft(node.left);
  right = isFullRight(node.right);
  if(left.equalTo(right)) return true;
  else return false;

  private void isFullLeft(Node n){
    if(n != null) left++;
      isFullLeft(n.left);
      isFullLeft(n.right);

  private void isFullRight(Node n){
    if(n != null) right++;
      isFullRight(n.left);
      isFullRight(n.right);
```

The code was just put together I'm not sure if I am right with actual code as  I am still learning Java. But is my idea correct at least? Thank you.

edit: No methods in methods? But this code has methods inside methods can you explain please?

```
public int size() {
        return(size(root)); 
    }
        private int size(Node node) { 
          if (node == null) return(0); 
          else { 
            return(size(node.left) + 1 + size(node.right));
```

Comment: Err, no, lolocal variables are, err, local.

Comment: Learn the difference between methods in a class (legal, and veeeery common) and methods in methods (not legal, and hence quite uncommon).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have methods inside of methods, you should define a class that is made up of those methods.

```
public class MyClass {

    .....

    public boolean isFull() {
        Node node = root;
        int left;
        int right;
        left = isFullLeft(node.left);
        right = isFullRight(node.right);
        if (left.equalTo(right)) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    private void isFullLeft(Node n) {
        if (n != null) left++;
        isFullLeft(n.left);
        isFullLeft(n.right);
    }

    private void isFullRight(Node n) {
        if (n != null) right++;
        isFullRight(n.left);
        isFullRight(n.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: im confused this method has a method inside a method and it works. Can you further explain please? I added the example code to  the question.

Comment: It does not have a method declaration inside of a method. Methods are allowed to call other methods, but you may not define a new method, inside of an existing method.